# Does Oracle thick client supports Database Change Notification?

Tags: database, oracle11g

Oracle Version - 11g 11.1
Oracle JDBC thin driver supports database change notification.
Thick client throws as error with unsupported feature.
Required privileges are granted for change notification to user.
Does Oracle thick client supports Database Change Notification?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28819

Answer (score 0):

No. The JDBC OCI driver (alias the thick driver) doesn't support Database Change Notification. This feature is only supported in the JDBC thin driver. Other features like AQ notifications are also only supported in the thin driver. By the way Oracle recommends to use the thin driver as it supports more features and offers the best performance.